# How can I restore a supervised device from iCloud

Tags: icloud, ios, mobile-device-management

I have an iPad that I want supervised. I can get it supervised but if I restore from a non-supervised backup, it removes the supervision.

Is it possible to restore a device from iCloud AND keep it supervised?

Answer (score 1):

No — restoring from iCloud will remove the supervision. There's no way round that, other than re-supervising the device afterwards.

Comment: What about an iTunes backup?

Comment: @emd Won't help. The supervision will still be removed.

Comment: Crappy. All I want to do is get all my home iOS devices supervised (so I can easily push out config changes like contact server, etc) but I don't want to have to set them all up again.

Comment: Right? It'd be nice if Apple Configurator saves all the details like a iCloud backup does. It would make deploying templates so much easier.